# spring-cloud-config-server - File System Backend searchLocation with placeholder

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

> The search locations can contain placeholders for {application},
>   {profile} and {label}

I am trying to segregate my properties into distinct directories like /app1/dev, /app2/dev, /app2/prod

I have set the **searchLocations** property in application.yml of my configuration server as given below.

```
spring:
 application:
  name: config-server   
 profiles:
  active: native
 cloud:
  config:
   server:
    native:
     #searchLocations: file:./config/{application},file:./config/{application}/{profile} # Trial 01
     searchLocations: file:./config/,file:./config/{application},file:./config/{application}/{profile} # Trial 02
```

I have kept the properties inside directories like zuul/prod, zuul/test
BUT the config server is unable to serve the configurations.

For the request `http://localhost:8082/zuul/prod` it gives

`{"name":"zuul","profiles":["prod"],"label":"master","propertySources":[]}`

Kindly clarify how to achieve this segregation.

**Environment** : Spring Cloud Angel.SR2 & 3

Comment: Only in Brixton, it is a new feature.

Comment: @spencergibb Thank you. I shall configure this after Brixton.SR. The documentation didn't differentiate the features in Angel/Brixton.

Comment: This is the documentation for Angel http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/docs/1.0.3/spring-cloud.html